# Chrome Policy with Email/Password fields

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

how to avoid chrome's policy on fields dos not belong to email/password fields,
example:
`<input type="text" id="account_search" autocomplete="off">`

I tried to change the id, add a name attribute, and change the type to `search` (i know its not gonna work), but none of that made the autocomplete disappear.